# search on specific element in HTML with jquery

Tags: jquery

My HTML is like this

```
    <div class="innerbox">
  <div class="simple-list02">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-child last-child odd-item">
        <h5 class="text-style02">
          <a href="/kontakt/find-medarbejder/ledelse/">Ledelse</a>
        </h5>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="simple-list02">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-child last-child odd-item">
        <h5 class="text-style02">
          <a href="/kontakt/find-medarbejder/administration/">Administration</a>
        </h5>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="simple-list02">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-child last-child odd-item">
        <h5 class="text-style02">
          <a href="/kontakt/find-medarbejder/omstillingbogholderi/">Omstilling/bogholderi</a>
        </h5>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I got an HTML input box like this

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="txtesearch" class="text" placeholder="Søg efter medarbejder">
```

Now what I want is When some one enters "Ledelse" in this textbox I want to hide all div  which got a class `"simple-list02"` excluding first one as it contains an `h5` with text "Ledelse" in it.
I had tried hard coding all the h5 text,But I don't believe its an ideal solution and as this is jquery there must be a smarter way to achieve this .can any one give me a hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.simple-list02:not(:has(h5:contains(' + searchTerm + ')))').hide();
```

The code above only hides, though. You may want to show all elements first, and then hide the ones that don't match, if the text changes.

```
 $('.simple-list02')
    .show()
    .not(':has(h5:contains(' + searchTerm + '))').hide();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fZLnh/)

Note that `:contains` is case sensitive. If you want something more advanced you may pass the set of simple-lists through a `.filter` function:

```
$('.simple-list02')
    .show()
    .filter(function() { 
        return $(this).find('h5').text().toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf( searchTerm.toLowerCase() ) == -1;
    })
    .hide();
```

Additionally, you could roll your own `:contains` selector, [as explained in this blog post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/):

```
// pre 1.8
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

// since 1.8
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```